# How to retrieve multiple rows from SQL Server database in C# using SqlDataReader?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqldatareader

I am trying to write a method which is supposed to retrieve multiple rows from a table in a database and use those data to instantiate a number of objects. However, as far as i can tell the database only returns the first row. When i do this:

```
public static List<Event> getMultipleEvents(string[] eventNames)
        {
            List<Event> rtnList = new List<Event>(); 

            string EventsToRetrieve = "";

            foreach (var item in eventNames)
            {
                if (EventsToRetrieve != "")
                {
                    EventsToRetrieve += " OR ";
                }

                EventsToRetrieve += "eventName = '";
                EventsToRetrieve += item;
                EventsToRetrieve += "' ";
            }
            // This is the string that the method constructs based on the input i am testing with 
            //"eventName = 'event six'  OR eventName = ' event two'  OR eventName = ' event one'  OR eventName = ' event seven' "
            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = Globals.GetSqlConnection())
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();

                using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE " + EventsToRetrieve + ";", sqlConnection))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (sqlDataReader != null)
                        {
                                while (sqlDataReader.Read())
                                {
                                    Event newEvent = new Event("", DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue);

                                    string startDateTimeStringFromDB = sqlDataReader["startDateDay"].ToString() + "-" + sqlDataReader["startDateMonth"].ToString() + "-" + sqlDataReader["startDateYear"].ToString();
                                    string endDateTimeStringFromDB = sqlDataReader["endDateDay"].ToString() + "-" + sqlDataReader["endDateMonth"].ToString() + "-" + sqlDataReader["endDateYear"].ToString();

                                    newEvent.EventName = sqlDataReader["eventName"].ToString();

                                    if (DateTime.TryParse(startDateTimeStringFromDB, out DateTime startDateTime))
                                    {
                                        newEvent.StartDate = startDateTime;
                                    }

                                    if (DateTime.TryParse(endDateTimeStringFromDB, out DateTime endDateTime))
                                    {
                                        newEvent.EndDate = endDateTime;
                                    }
                                    rtnList.Add(newEvent);
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return rtnList;
        }
```

Can anyone explain to me what i am doing wrong ? I Also tried wrapping the while loop in a do while loop as suggested here [How to read multiple resultset from SqlDataReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448899/how-to-read-multiple-resultset-from-sqldatareader) but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Unrelated tip: Rather than having 3 columns `startDateYear`, `startDateMonth`, `startDateDay`, consider having one column `startDate` of type `date`. Aside from the storage space saving, and the validation of values being inserted and the SQL queries being easier to write, the C# is also easier to write... Several of those lines collapse into: `newEvent.StartDate = sqlDataReader.GetDateTime(startDateOrdinal);` where *startDateOrdinal* is the column number in the resultset. You could look that up with `GetOrdinal`, but if you don't use `SELECT *` you'd know which column it was.

Comment: It's worth looking at [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful), including some of the less highly voted answers.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem to have any error in your code. however I believe that your query has errors.

First of all never ever use string concatenation when you are building your SQL Query. Instead use [Parameterized Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements).

with the parameterized queries, it is even easier to debug your SQL statement since it does not include conditional string concatenations.

Comment: A `;` at the end of a T-SQL statement ***IS*** a valid character - in fact, in some cases, it's even **required** and it's generally a recommend best practice to terminate each T-SQL statement with a `;` in new SQL code being written

Comment: I checked it. It works in both ways. I am editing my answer. thank you